# iphone switch between navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there a way to switch from one navigation controller to the other navigation controller, which can trigger by button action?

Comment: You have multiple navigation controllers and you want to switch between them?

Comment: sorta. I have multiple navigation controller under tabbar controller. I want to switch to new navigation controller as root when certain event is occurred

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "of course", but you need to be more specific.  Are you talking about a subordinate NavController, or a TabBar, or a modal view?  See Apple's doc "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS", and give us more of a context.

Comment: um yea, I think i need to clarify my situation. I have several navi controller under tabbar controller, what i wannna do is when button is pressed on any of those navigation controller, switch to whole different view that new navigation controller is root not tabbar controller

Comment: Will it eventually pop back to the tabBar controller? (ie should the new navController be a modal controller?).